# HTML/CSS Positioning Issue with asp:Label and span

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

When I do the following:

```
<asp:Label CssClass="someField" runat="server">*</asp:Label> 
<asp:Label ID="someID" runat="server" Text="SomeText" AssociatedControlID="someACID"></asp:Label>
```

Or:

```
<span class="someField">*</span>
<asp:Label ID="someID" runat="server" Text="SomeText" AssociatedControlID="someACID"></asp:Label>
```

Css someField:

```
span.someField {
   color: #CC0000;
   font-weight: 600;
}
```

Css for label:

```
form label {
    clear: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0 3px 4px 0;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

the output I get is

> SomeText*

When what I want is

> *SomeText

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: show the class definition for "someField" please

Comment: So flip the contents around, set someField to "SomeText" and flip the asterisk to someID

Comment: I showed the class definition for someField

Comment: I tried flipping it around one of the first things I did, but no luck very weird.

Comment: @Anicho: When you post questions, you should leave out the salutations, because it makes it harder to get a feel for the question when looking at the summary.

Comment: Thanks @James Johnson and @bemused there is no link to someID in the css. We are using `form input` in css to manipulate those bits. Its working now thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting `float:left` on the label you are taking it out of the flow of the document and causing it to render before the span. You need to either set the span to be a block layout and float it left as well or remove the float from the label.

UPDATE:

There's a good description of what floating does to elements and some considerations here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Cheers buddy :D so simples, gotta fix some other issues now lol the css has changed a lot of fields but all simple fixes thank a chu.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
form label:after {
    content: "*";
}
```

Comment: It is 2011, we should be using CSS3.

Comment: When the majority of our customers/unique visitors are using modern browsers we will use css3. We can encourage users to upgrade but at the end of the day they use what they use we cater for what they use to the best of our ability.

Comment: Enjoy specifically having to develop for nonstandard, insecure and obsolete browsers then.

Comment: Ahaha don't worry the money made from these so called obsolete browsers justifies my reasoning so I will enjoy the fruits of developing for them. Only thing I can agree on is that I am falling behind on latest best practices and coding standards.

Comment: That is a fair statement, there is a point where the cost of supporting them outweighs the revenue it will gain.

Comment: Technically it was CSS 2.1 but the offending browsers not supporting it is still the same.

Comment: @Chris Marisic your right, but thats why we invest so much into analytics to make sure we are targetting as many visitors as possible.